# php - is it possible to define properties for methods?

Tags: php, oop

I would like to define some properties in a method that are contained within that method i.e not the the entire class. But want to do this from the instance of the object. Is that possible? The code below does not work.

```
class foo{


var $x;


function __construct(){


}

function abc(){

echo $y;

}   

}   


$new = new  foo();

$new->abc->y = "bar";
```

Comment: That hasn't worked

Comment: [Suggested reading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * I have trimmed this down because of redundant entries, and only 
 * modified what you had written
 */

class foo
{
    /*
     * I have made this public so you can access this globally
     */

     public function abc($y)
     {
         echo $y;
     }   
}

$new = new foo();

/*
 * Instead of passing a value directly to the variable inside the
 * method, I made the method accept properties that will modify
 * the variable. You cannot do this if you have not made the method
 * 'public'.
 */

$new->abc("bar"); // the method contains an echo statement, so it will echo "bar"

?>
```

Hope that helps.